# NAN - AsyncProgressWorker has corrupted members

Tags: c++, node.js, dll

I've created an *AsyncProgressWorker* which creates an instance and call the constructor in my C++ DLL through an interface. The *init* creates a thread which does work permanently. Everythings fine so far...

This is my **nodeModul.cc**

```
MyModule mod* = 0;    

NAN_METHOD(init) {
  Nan::HandleScope scope;

  ... doing stuff with the arguments

  // create instance
  mod = new MyModule(nanCallback, p1, p2, p3);

  // queue the worker instance onto the thread-pool
  Nan::AsyncQueueWorker(mod);
}

NAN_METHOD(setIntSetting) {
  Nan::HandleScope scope;

  if (mod) {        
    ... do the argument thing

    mod->setIntSetting(p, v, r);
  }
  else { ... }
}
```

I've added some functions to call interface's methods. I'd like to forward data which the running DLL-thread should use from now on.

Please find my **MyModule.h**

```
class MyModule : public Nan::AsyncProgressWorker {
public:
  // Constructor
  SubvisMocker(Nan::Callback *callback, const long p1, const long p2, const long p3) : Nan::AsyncProgressWorker(callback)
    , p1_(p1), p2_(p2), p3_(p3)
{
    myMod = nullptr;

    std::cout << "members: " << p1_ << "/" << p2_ << "/" << p3_ << std::endl;

}
// Destructor
~MyModule() {}

// Execute
void Execute(const Nan::AsyncProgressWorker::ExecutionProgress &progress) {

    if (!myMod) {
        myMod = new ns::Dll_Object();

        myMod->init(p1_, p2_);
    }               
    Sleep(200);
}

void HandleProgressCallback() {
    std::cout << "ProgressCallback() - was called" << std::endl;
}

// Execution completed
void HandleOKCallback() {
    Nan::HandleScope scope;
    callback->Call(0, NULL);
}

// 
// set method
void setIntSetting(const int p, const int v, const int r) {
    Nan::HandleScope scope;
    std::cout << "members: " << p1_ << "/" << p2_ << "/" << p3_ << std::endl;
    myMod->intSetting(p, v, r);
}
private:
  long p1_;
  long p2_;
  long p3_;

  ns::IDllObject* myMod;
```

};

The functions in the AsyncProgressWorker are getting called, but unfortunately, the pointer to the running instance (**myMod**) of the DLL is in 95% of all cases corrupt (same like all other member variables). In 5%, the call is going through and behaves like it should. Also the cout in *setIntSetting* is mostly wrong and sometimes correct.

*Init* gets called right after launching the node app whereby *setIntSetting* get's called after a POST message from client-side GUI.

The same structure and design works perfect with another module, but that one is not a shared lib. Could it be, that there is a problem? Is the usage of a DLL that different?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, that I was calling the *init* method directly after booting the app. A call of *setIntSetting* from the GUI was using a different context (maybe there is a better wording). So calling *init* from the GUI as well solves this issue!!! But it's still interesting that the pointer to **myMod** is valid. I better don't store this pointer as a global variable.

Maybe someone could comment, how I get the pointer without using a global variable? Than I also can start a new instance in each opened browser window, user, whatever...